# phpcs - How to allow same line braces when promoting constructors in PHP 8

Tags: php, phpcs, php-8

This is my first question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1096219/thiagobraga?tab=questions). I'm very happy for that!

I would like to know if there's some [**`phpcs`**](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) configuration that can override the same line braces rule. For example, when using [PHP 8 new constructor promotion feature](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion), in some cases we don't need any content in the constructor. So it would be nice if `phpcs` could allow this code:

```php
/**
 * UserService constructor
 *
 * @param UserRepository $userRepository
 * @param BillingService $billingService
 */
public function __construct(
    protected UserRepository $userRepository,
    protected BillingService $billingService
) {}
```

Or even that:

```php
/**
 * BillingService constructor
 *
 * @param BillingRepository $billingRepository
 */
public function __construct(protected BillingRepository $billingRepository) {}
```

But it raises the warning, in VS Code for example, "Closing brace must be on a line by itself". I don't want to disable the rule, just allow an exception automatically when using constructor promotion.

The `phpcs.xml.dist` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/phpcs.xsd">
  <rule ref="PSR1"/>
  <rule ref="PSR2">
    <exclude name="PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName"/>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Are you running the latest PHPCS release? It seems that they've updated it to support PHP8 9 days ago with version [3.6.0](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/releases/tag/3.6.0). If that doesn't do the trick there's multiple ways to disable a specific sniff for a file ([source](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/1179))

Comment: Thank you, friend. I installed using `composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"`, so I don't know which version was resolved. I edited `composer.json` and `composer update`. I don't know exactly if I need to do anything, but it didn't work. Looking at Github changelog, I added this rule `<rule ref="Squiz.WhiteSpace.ScopeKeywordSpacing"/>` in my `phpcs.dist.xml` file, but it still displays the error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To see what version is currently running you can run `composer show` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185459/how-to-get-list-of-all-installed-packages-along-with-version-in-composer)). As for disabling you might have excluded a different sniff. To find out what exact one is causing the error you could run PHPCS with the `-s` option [as per this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730588/php-codesniffer-show-sniff-that-failed).

Comment: Someone created an issue on Github for this specific case, [check here](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/3291).